# javascript: The types of functions and when to use each

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript, and have noticed that the language has numerous ways to declare a function.

Easiest (for me) would be the following:

```
function foo(test) {
    return test + 1;
};
```

However, there also seem to be:

```
var foo = function *optional*(test){
    return test + 1;
};
```

In this method (^), what difference does it make if you assign a name? will it basically say 'This function can be found under foo, or under *optional*'

Another option seems to be an 'Arrow function' that is a lot more simplified compared to the others, I understand it can also be written with curled brackets...

```
var foo = (test) => return test + 1;
```

`

```
var foo = (test) => {
    return test + 1;
};
```

Also, I think you are able to explicitly say the word function in your arrow definitions, as follows:

```
var foo = function(test) => {
    return 'test' + 1;
};
```

When do I use each, which one is more standard, what are the explicit differences other than how they are written, and is there anything else I should know about functions?

Comment: Use what you prefer. This is an open-ended question, and has no correct answer.

Comment: Is there a difference? I am asking in what situation is each used. This is the only forum I know of that would provide a wide variety of opinion, and provides a fair shot at finding professionals in the field. @FrankerZ

Comment: There is a different, and going through the javascript documentation will tell you the differences.

Comment: To clarify, there is no difference between an arrow function and a 'standard' function except for its syntax. It acts the exact same way, just affects readability and might save you a few bytes.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, @dandeto ! Another person mentions Hoisting, should this be a concern of mine when using the arrow functions, or generally those functions which are stored in a variable? If I understand correctly, functions are stored in the memory first, but variables aren't until they are initialized, or given a value...so, if I fill a variable with a function, that counts it as initialized. HOWEVER: I am unable to use the variable function prior to being initialized, due to it technically not existing yet as far as the code is concerned? [Sorry if I'm rambling absurdities!]

Comment: If you are declaring arrow functions as a variable (as opposed to being anonymous) they behave exactly the same as a 'standard' function stored in a variable, so they both are affected by hoisting. If you organize your code properly, hoisting isn't a big deal. And yes, you understand how hoisting works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question. There is no major difference. However this is this interesting problem called "hoisting" that may happen that will really drive you crazy. Here is a link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Go out and look for any video with Douglas Crockford. He is the writer of "Javascript the Good Parts".

Comment: Thanks! I was using 'Codeacademy', and did not feel they sufficiently explained it. Which would you recommend using in day-to-day? If it matters, I am looking to get into web-development...

Comment: If I understand correctly, using the methods that involve a variable could lead to issues with 'hoisting', if not defined in their completeness prior to being called in the program?
Therefore it would be advisable to use the simple function foo() {}; declaration?
 @Rich K. (However, it does not matter when it is defined, as long as I initialize it first?]

Comment: Just learning to code javascript, use the function foo() {} way for now. It will save you a lot of headaches. Later on when you get more comfortable, try out the other ways. Have fun and definitely watch some Crockford videos, that guy is a Javascript Rockstar.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643450/10149507) mentioned above, there is another point you must get, the functions name.

Take a look at [MDN Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), you will see what tricky can be. A good function naming is very useful and more especially when debugging.

There are two typo in your code, I fix it

```
var foo = (test) => return test + 1; // return already is '=>'
var foo = function(test) => { // 'function' can't go with '=>'
    return 'test' + 1;
};
```

Should be

```
var foo = (test) => test + 1;
var foo = function(test) {
    return 'test' + 1;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, reading the linked page now! :)